# Get only published pages from pages library in CQWP

Tags: sharepoint-designer, xslt, content-query-web-part

I am working on CQWP web part and all weorks fine except one thing.

In my CQWP webpart, it rollup all pages of specific content type and display in CQWP webpart. But problem is that it also return all pages includes draft pages and published pages. And i want to display only published pages in CQWP.

I have tried solution in this [Post](http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/6614983:BlogPost:99605) but it cant solve my problem. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: If you wanna show pages that are published you should be able to filter them out by using "Checked Out To = blank" ( leave it blank for the blank condition ). This will return only the pages that currently are published.

Comment: It doesn't have option of "Checked Out To" in query portion of CQWP for filtration.

Comment: Can you show the XML input and XSLT you are currently using? The referred to link shows an extensive (and quite badly written) stylesheet. Possibly you currently use the copy idiom and not the delete idiom for the affected elements?